# Effect of changing current sense resistor value in amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, resistors, current-measurement, gain, instrumentation-amplifier

I am trying to implement a current output amplifier circuit shown below. Current is measured across sense resistor Rs to adjust input voltage Vin.

[image]

Gain: G = -I<sub>out</sub>/V<sub>in</sub> = R2/(Gain<sub>IA1</sub> × R1 × RS)

The gain of this circuit is set at 1 with

- R2 = 1 kΩ
- R1 = 100 kΩ
- RS = 0.01 Ω
- RL is the load.

It has an instrumentation amplifier IA1 on the feedback path for less noise and better resolution. The gain of IA1 is also 1.

If I decide to increase resistance of Rs and decrease resistance of R1 while keeping the gain at 1, how would changing sense resistor value affect my system performance?

Answer (score 0):

you formula for gain is not correct,

\$ \frac{- I_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{R_2}{R_1*IA1*R_S}\$

for your purpose, you need to 
change R1

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. By changing the resistance of R1 & RS, would that affect the my system performance? Is there any advantage of changing sense resistor value?

Comment: @Linh, by changing R1, input impedance will be change. if you change Rs, you should aware of power dissipation, \$  P_d = R_s * i^2 \$,

Comment: What if I keep the same value for R1 and change the value of R2, what should i notice?

Comment: @Linh, I think R2 could just change the loop gain and this cause instability in the loop. I don't know which value this instability happens. you could simulate this circuit for instability region.

Comment: Could you give me more detail on how it causes instability in the loop? Isnt that the point of using negative feedback is to improve stability?

Comment: @Linh, the explanation is not easy, but for intuition imagine that if RL generates a delay in the current (when Vin is changed) then your sense Res may not control loop because of delay. For example when your loop gain is high but your feedback is just uV or mV then noise makes this circuit unstable. I think to use this circuit and check it with your load. you can check stability in software.

Comment: @Linh - Think of it this way. If OA1 is fast enough, changes in its output will be delayed around the loop compared to the changes for them to interact with each other. Your setup is almost certain to oscillate. The cure is to put a small(ish) feedback capacitor across OA1. The exact value will depend both on the speed of IA1 and the loop gain. Start with something like 1000 pF. And yes, this will slow down the response of your loop.